# Sharepoint 2013 client document library Column validation

Tags: c#, list, validation, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I try to upload file to document library with metadata. When I enter validation for one column the file does not upload even data is correct or incorrect. Always show this exception

> List data validation failed

My Code Is

```
if (documentsList.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary)
{   
    Folder DocLib = documentsList.RootFolder;

    FileCreationInformation DocItemInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
    DocItemInfo.ContentStream = GetImageFile();
    DocItemInfo.Overwrite = true;

    DocItemInfo.Url = "Test.JPG";
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = DocLib.Files.Add(DocItemInfo);

    ListItem newItem = file.ListItemAllFields;

    FillSPLitem(ref newItem); // To get MetaData

    newItem.Update();

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: please check if it is related to your column validation or can you please tell your validation.
The formula must return a True or False.